# Is there a SQLite query validator lib?

Tags: java, javascript, sqlite

Is there a Java or javascript SQLite query validator library that I could pass a raw query and validate the input.

Comment: What do you mean by validate?

Comment: "sqlite syntax checker" I pass it a raw query and it will let me know where the error is, Android have something similar, example output: "SQLiteException: near ";": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT "

Comment: This question is not related to ORM.

Answer (score 3):

Parsing SQL is too complex for doing this outside the database, and it would be almost impossible to get all the details of the specific SQL dialect right.

If you want to avoid executing the query, prefix it with [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) or [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) and check whether *that* commands results in an error.